# How to convert returns to prices?

Tags: r

I am curious how I revert from log-returns to prices.  Here's an example:

```
> a1 <- c(88.23, 88.44, 88.55, 88.77, 88.99)
> a1 
[1] 88.23 88.44 88.55 88.77 88.99
> a2 <- diff(log(a1))
> a2 
[1] 0.002377315 0.001243008 0.002481391 0.002475249
```

a1 is prices, a2 is returns.  How would I go from a2 back to a1?  Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should do:

```
> Reduce(function(x,y) {x * exp(y)}, a2, init=a1[1], accumulate=T)
[1] 88.23 88.44 88.55 88.77 88.99
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to use something like

```
a3 <- exp(cumsum(a2))
```

Alternatively, you could use

```
a3 <- cumprod(exp(a2))
```

But these will be off because you need to add back the initial price to each value.

Comment: A computationally more efficient (not that that is going to matter) is: a1[1] * c(1, exp(cumsum(a2)))

Comment: @PatrickBurns I probably should have done it that way because its the true inverse of the operations.  Updated